# Codable Parsing issue

Tags: json, swift, codable

I am trying to parse the API response using Codable class.

Below is the response :

```
{"status":200,"message":"","success":1,"data":[{"event_id":"26","event_name":"Mens Night","event_desc":"Hot Mens Night","from_date":"2019-02-08","to_date":"2019-03-09","bar_id":"62","bar_names":"Autumn Bar & Bistro","bar_ids":"62","offer_image":"https:\/\/www.tippler.app\/manager\/uploads\/events\/mens_night.jpg","from_time":"19:00:00","to_time":"01:30:00"},{"event_id":"36","event_name":"Karaoke Night","event_desc":"Karaoke NIght with Brian Rub","from_date":"2019-02-08","to_date":"2019-02-09","bar_id":"146","bar_names":"Amuse Resto Bar","bar_ids":"146","offer_image":"https:\/\/www.tippler.app\/manager\/uploads\/events\/Screenshot_20190208-155223__011.jpg","from_time":"21:00:00","to_time":"01:00:00"},{"event_id":"37","event_name":"Sufi Nights","event_desc":"Singers From mumbai","from_date":"2019-02-08","to_date":"2019-02-09","bar_id":"66","bar_names":"Cavalry The Lounge","bar_ids":"66","offer_image":"https:\/\/www.tippler.app\/manager\/uploads\/events\/SUFI-FEATURED.jpg","from_time":"20:00:00","to_time":"01:30:00"},{"event_id":"39","event_name":"BOLLYWOOD NIGHT","event_desc":"BHANGRA AND LIVE DHOL","from_date":"2019-02-09","to_date":"2019-02-10","bar_id":"103","bar_names":"B Desi","bar_ids":"103","offer_image":"https:\/\/www.tippler.app\/manager\/uploads\/events\/bollywood-nights-1.jpg","from_time":"21:00:00","to_time":"01:00:00"}],"error_dev":""}
```

I Codable class is :

```
struct Events: Codable {
    var event_id: String
    var event_name: String
    var event_desc: String
    var from_date: String
    var to_date: String
    var bar_id: String
    var bar_names: String
    var bar_ids: String
    var offer_image: String
    var from_time: String
    var to_time: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case event_id = "event_id"
        case event_name = "event_name"
        case event_desc = "event_desc"
        case from_date = "from_date"
        case to_date = "to_date"
        case bar_id = "bar_id"
        case bar_names = "bar_names"
        case bar_ids = "bar_ids"
        case offer_image = "offer_image"
        case from_time = "from_time"
        case to_time = "to_time"
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(event_id, forKey: .event_id)
        try container.encode(event_name, forKey: .event_name)
        try? container.encode(event_desc, forKey: .event_desc)
        try? container.encode(from_date, forKey: .from_date)
        try container.encode(to_date, forKey: .to_date)
        try container.encode(bar_id, forKey: .bar_id)
        try container.encode(bar_names, forKey: .bar_names)
        try container.encode(bar_ids, forKey: .bar_ids)
        try container.encode(offer_image, forKey: .offer_image)
        try container.encode(from_time, forKey: .from_time)
        try container.encode(to_time, forKey: .to_time)
    }


    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        event_id = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .event_id)
        event_name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .event_name)
        event_desc = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .event_desc)
        from_date = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .from_date)
        to_date = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .to_date)
        bar_id = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .bar_id)
        bar_names = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .bar_names)
        bar_ids = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .bar_ids)
        offer_image = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .offer_image)
        from_time = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .from_time)
        to_time = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .to_time)
    }


}
```

It is returning with the response error

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "event_id", intValue: nil),
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:
>   [CodingKeys>(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil),
>   _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"event_id\",
>   intValue: nil) (\"event_id\").", underlyingError: nil))

please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your codable   structure not matching with response as they have status , message success and errorDev key

Try this

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let status: Int?
    let message: String?
    let success: Int?
    let data: [Events]?
    let errorDev: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status, message, success, data
        case errorDev = "error_dev"
    }
}
struct Events: Codable {
    let eventID, eventName, eventDesc, fromDate: String?
    let toDate, barID, barNames, barIDs: String?
    let offerImage: String?
    let fromTime, toTime: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case eventID = "event_id"
        case eventName = "event_name"
        case eventDesc = "event_desc"
        case fromDate = "from_date"
        case toDate = "to_date"
        case barID = "bar_id"
        case barNames = "bar_names"
        case barIDs = "bar_ids"
        case offerImage = "offer_image"
        case fromTime = "from_time"
        case toTime = "to_time"
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I can provide you more generic solution. Suppose all API has the same response but only `data` key is  different then

```
struct GeneralResponse<T:Codable>: Codable {
     let status: Int?
     let message: String?
     let success: Int?
     let data: T?
     let errorDev: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case message = "msg"
        case code = "code"
        case data = "data" 
      // add more keys
    }

    public init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
        let contaienr = try  decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        message = try contaienr.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)
        // Decode Other keys 

        do {
            let object = try contaienr.decodeIfPresent(T.self, forKey: .data)
            data = object

        } catch {
            data = nil
        }

    }

}
```

Now For every Response You Can

use `GenericResponse<[Event]>` 
or `GenericResponse<Login>` 
or `GenericResponse<[UserList]>`

Hope it is helpful

Comment: It's a pretty bad suggestion to declare **all** struct members schematically and thoughtlessly as optional.

Comment: @vadian I don't understand why , could you please explain that

Comment: JSON sent by an API is actually a very reliable format. So first you should declare all struct members as non-optional and catch and fix errors for the keys which can be missing by changing the type to optional. On the other hand if everything is optional and something goes wrong, you will see nothing and you don't know why. And unwrapping optionals which are never `nil` is pretty annoying.

Comment: @vadian Yes I understand this. I prefer to use optional because There are chances that API is not sending parameter (null) so instead of handling error I am letting codable to continue with optional or nil value.  and later I am handling this with required fields . and one more thing is API may contains many unnecessary fields so it may too long to handle each and every field. and with optional we have surety that app will never crash.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Events : Codabel {
   let status: Int?
   let message: String?
   let success: Int?
   let data: [Event]?
   let errorDev: String?
}

struct Datum: Codable {
    let eventID, eventName, eventDesc, fromDate, offerImage, fromTime, toTime : String?
    let toDate, barID, barNames, barIDs: String?
}
```

no need to write down CodingKeys for snake cases,

While decoding, you just write

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let responseModel = try decoder.decode(Events.self, from: data) // data from response
```

Comment: It's a pretty bad suggestion to declare **all** struct members schematically and thoughtlessly as optional.

Comment: it returns eventID and barID as nil

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of errors in your code as follow...

- `event_id` is of type `String` in your code but is is `Int` type.
- `bar_id` is of type `String` in your code but is is `Int` type.
- `bar_ids` is of type `String` in your code but is is `Int` type.

You need to correct these variable types.

> Note: Wherever in response you find a number then it will be of `Int` type, a number with a decimal points like 12.123 then if will be of `Double` type by default. Directly assuming it as string is not acceptable in swift.